# ActiveMQ Artemis split brain on failback to master broker

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I have 4 master/slave broker pairs in Artemis cluster. Those are paired to each one on different servers as below are configurations for one of the pair. I use `tcp` to connect to brokers and URL to connect to broker is in two way. a) Some consumers connect to one broker, e. g. `tcp://server1:61616?params` b) Some consumers connect to all brokers (different queue) `(tcp://server1:61616,tcp://server2:61616,tcp://server3:61616,tcp://server4:61616)?params`

I am facing 2 issues currently

1. When I shutdown master broker, slave takes up as master but only those consumers which has URL (a) connects to active slave but other consumers which has URL (b) are connected to other master brokers (server2, server3, server4) instead of active slave.
2. When I restart master again, sometimes slave does not take up as a backup again but instead both master and slave acts as active and get below exception on slave. I have to restart cluster to get all master slave as intended.

```java
There is a possible split brain on nodeID a517ea1e-4edd-11ed-b9ac-005056a4dfbd, coming from connectors TopologyMember[id=a517ea1e-4edd-11ed-b9ac-005056a4dfbd, connector=Pair[a=TransportConfiguration(name=netty-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?trustStorePassword=****&port=61616&keyStorePassword=****&sslEnabled=true&host=10-0-0-1&trustStorePath=server1_truststore-jks&keyStorePath=server1_keystore-jks, b=null], backupGroupName=p1, scaleDownGroupName=null]. Topology update ignored.
```

HA configs as below

**master**

```xml
<ha-policy>
  <replication>
     <master>
         <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
         <group-name>p1</group-name>
     </master>
  </replication>
</ha-policy>
```

**slave**

```xml
<ha-policy>
  <replication>
      <slave>
         <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
         <group-name>p1</group-name>
       </slave>
   </replication>
</ha-policy>
```

What could be the issues with this?

Comment: I'm not sure what could be causing the master to activate when there's a slave with the same node ID. However, I recommend you migrate to the new [pluggable quorum voting](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#pluggable-quorum-vote-replication-configurations) which can integrate with ZooKeeper. This is superior to relying on the brokers themselves for quorum voting and split-brain mitigation. It will also potentially allow you to reduce the size of your cluster to a single HA pair.

Comment: For issue 1, when I limit number of consumers on a queue with `max-consumers` attribute to distribute consumers evenly and consumers from failed master should connect only to respective slave on failover. But no consumer with URL (b) connecting to slave instead they keep hanging and connect back to master when it starts. How to mitigate this?

Comment: Which is the version pluggable quorum voting available from?

Comment: I can't really comment without more details about the URL the clients are using. Can you provide the _full_ URL?

Comment: Pluggable quorum voting was introduced in 2.18.0 via [ARTEMIS-2716](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2716). The [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) at this point is 2.26.0.

Comment: Issue seems to be due to restarted master node is not coming back to the cluster and acting as standalone broker. Whenever restarted node comes back to cluster quorum voting is happening and slave becomes backup. I'll create new question for it.